# How to run a tcl/tk application from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I have a large tcl/tk application that I want to run from tkinter, so that I can deal with the application with python. Here is an example tcl code:

```
package require Tk

wm title . "Feet to Meters"
grid [ttk::frame .c -padding "3 3 12 12"] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nwes
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1; grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

grid [ttk::entry .c.feet -width 7 -textvariable feet] -column 2 -row 1 -sticky we
grid [ttk::label .c.meters -textvariable meters] -column 2 -row 2 -sticky we
grid [ttk::button .c.calc -text "Calculate" -command calculate] -column 3 -row 3 -sticky w

grid [ttk::label .c.flbl -text "feet"] -column 3 -row 1 -sticky w
grid [ttk::label .c.islbl -text "is equivalent to"] -column 1 -row 2 -sticky e
grid [ttk::label .c.mlbl -text "meters"] -column 3 -row 2 -sticky w

foreach w [winfo children .c] {grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5}
focus .c.feet
bind . <Return> {calculate}

proc calculate {} {  
   if {[catch {
       set ::meters [expr {round($::feet*0.3048*10000.0)/10000.0}]
   }]!=0} {
       set ::meters ""
   }
}
```

I can run it by following python code:

```
from Tkinter import Tcl, Tk

tcl = Tcl()
tcl.evalfile("test.tcl")
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

**The first question**

the `root` window is just for keeping the Python process alive. I want to know can I remove this window and keep the window created by test.tcl keep running?

**The second question**

I can use `tcl.eval()` to call TCL functions, and `tcl.createcommand()` to call python function from TCL script. I want to know is this kind of call thread-safe?

Comment: Tcl prefers to be single-threaded (if you don't explicitly ask for it) and Tk is even keener on this.